# Accessing data from a remote JSONP Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I have this JSONP object displayed on a site that generates 3 random numbers. I am trying to access it using the following script embedded in a HTML document.

```
<script>
var url = 'http://dev.apalfrey.me/workspace/te2006-te2801/';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', //uses GET function
    url: url, //stored URL in var
    data: {
        'callback': 'randomNum'
    },

    jsonpCallback: 'randomNum',
    contentType: 'application/jsonp',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(randomNum.num1); //ERROR IS HERE randomNum.
});
</script>
```

The JSONP object looks like this:

[image: JSONP Object displaying random numbers]

Currently I am getting an error. **"Can't find variable: randomNum"** That tells me that I am not targetting the object correctly.
It is also important to note that the JSONP object does appear in my resources when I hit F12.

Any suggestions on how to target the remote JSONP object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your `done()` handler. You're attempting to use a variable named `randomNum` which doesn't exist. Instead you need to use the `response` variable as passed to the handler function.

Also note that `response` will be an array, so you need to access the required item by it's index, eg `response[0].num1`. Try this:

```js
var url = 'http://dev.apalfrey.me/workspace/te2006-te2801/';

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  jsonpCallback: 'randomNum',
  dataType: 'jsonp'
}).done(function(response) {
  console.dir(response);
  console.log(response[0].num1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that if your intention is to simply generate a random number then AJAX is huge overkill. You can just use `Math.random()`.

Comment: `Math.random()`? Nah, needs more jQuery.

Comment: Of course I could use Math.random(). This is just an exercise to help me learn how accessing a JSON object works. Thank you, I will take a look at my code and add the changes when I have the time (next 24hours). I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I get it working. Thanks  @Rory McCrossan.

Comment: Just making sure you were aware :) Glad to help